# i have a problam with reading binary file in c++

Tags: c++, binary, buffer, binaryfiles, fstream

i have a problem reading the input file which is binary , when i compile this code i get question marks in the terminal while reading a sql file .

my problem is that i want to convert byte to char , i tried with this code but no result .

```cpp
Item::Item(const std::string &file_name) {
    this->stfile.open(file_name,
                      std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    this->input_file.open(file_name,
                          std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    if (this->stfile.is_open() == false) {
        this->stfile.open(file_name, std::ios::in | std::ios::out |
                                         std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);
    }
    if (this->stfile.is_open() == false) {
        throw exception::CanNotOpenStorageFile(file_name);
    }
    this->stfile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);

    assert(this->stfile.tellg() % 4096 == 0);
    this->_count_pages = this->stfile.tellg() / 4096;
}

Item::~Item() { this->stfile.close(); }

void Item::read([[maybe_unused]] const Page::id_t page_id,
                [[maybe_unused]] std::byte *buffer) {
    this->stfile.seekg(page_id * 4096, std::ios::beg);

    this->stfile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(buffer), 4096);
    for(int i=0; i<4096; i++({
        this->input_file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(buffer[i]), 4096);
    }
    this->input_file.close();
}

void Item::write([[maybe_unused]] const Page::id_t page_id,
                 [[maybe_unused]] const std::byte *data) {
    this->stfile.seekp(page_id * 4096, std::ios::beg);
    this->stfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(data), 4096);
}
```

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<4096; i++({` looks terribly wrong.

Comment: All those `this->`s give me a headache.

Comment: 4096 represents bytes and not in integer, already defined in bytes but here to explain.

Comment: Your state that the problem is converting byte to char, so if you have a `std::byte b;` then converting it is simply `char c = static_cast<char>(b);`